# $scope function in Ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http

everybody . I a new to angularJS and i have a question.
I want to get Name of StringHP by getStringbyName(StringHpByCode) function.

```
  <div> {{getStringbyName(StringHpByCode)}} </div>
    $scope.StringHpByCode='A11111';
    $scope.getStringbyName=function(StringHP)
    {
        AjaxHelper(HocPhanUri +"?stringhp="+StringHP, 'GET').then(function (response) {
        return response.data.name;
        }
    }
    function AjaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        return $http({
            method: method,
            url: uri,
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        })
    }
```

But my browser show error:

> angular.js:13424 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations
>   reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [].

how to resolve it.? 
Sorry, my bad English.

Comment: Show your AjaxHelper

Comment: function AjaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        return $http({
            method: method,
            url: uri,
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        })
    }

Comment: Show also your controller where the getChuoibyName is.

Comment: i doubt your `html`, please if you could create a `fiddle` or `plnk`

Comment: getStringbyName  is a $scope function. it is  $scope.getStringbyName=function(StringHP)

Answer (score 0):

Putting a function call on inside {{ }} will call it many times when your mouse is hover it so you do multiple useless $http calls for the same data (or worse, more the mouse is over more it do calls and more it take times) .

Can you call this function on another event like button click or like this ?

```
<div> {{stringResult}} </div>


$scope.StringHpByCode='A11111';
$scope.stringResult = null ;
$scope.getStringbyName=function(StringHP)
{
    AjaxHelper(HocPhanUri +"?stringhp="+StringHP, 'GET').then(function (response) {
        $scope.stringResult = response.data.name;
    }
}
function AjaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    return $http({
        method: method,
        url: uri,
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    })
}
$scope.getStringbyName($scope.StringHpByCode ) ;
```

Comment: yes, thanks you. i only want display  {{getStringbyName(StringHpByCode)}}. how to display it?